# Will they serve alcohol to a Muslim in the Maldives?

Tags: alcohol, islam, maldives

I read everywhere that alcohol beverages are prohibited in the Maldives. However, they also state that it's allowed to sell it in the resorts to non-Muslims as the resorts are private properties.

Is that really enforced? do they check the religion for real upon request to ensure that you are a non-Muslim?

To make it an easy question: can a Muslim drink there, especially if the person has a name generally only used by Muslims?

Comment: They can't "check the religion for real", at least for foreigners. They can only guess or ask.

Comment: @ugoren In many Muslim-majority countries (eg Indonesia) your religion is listed on your ID, and having a Muslim-sounding name can also be used as a proxy.

Comment: Not answer-worthy so just adding as a comment, but a Turkish-German friend of mine visited the Maldives and drank no problem. I do wonder how things would have been if he  only had a Turkish ID.

Comment: This sounds a bit like the [No true Scotsman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_true_Scotsman) fallacy, but wouldn't the fact that one is willing to drink alcohol be sufficient proof that one isn't a true Muslim?

Comment: @RayButterworth No, because many Muslims do drink alcohol. To be clear, in countries which ban Muslims specifically from drinking it's usually impossible to stop "being Muslim". That is, if the state considers you were born a Muslim, you cannot convert, and the law will always apply to you regardless of whether you want it to.

Comment: FWIW, when I was in Turkey (allegedly 98% Muslim), 20-50% of the people I saw were smoking, and there was alcohol for sale seemingly on every block.  The ubiquitous police were unconcerned.  This was not only in İstanbul, but in the far less touristy Van.  (But pork was unavailable!)

Comment: @WGroleau Turkey is officially secular.  Most people choose to be Muslim but it's not forced on you.

Answer (score 4):

Legally, if you are a Muslim who is 18 years old or older, you can technically buy alcohol, but it is [banned for the local population](https://wikitravel.org/en/Maldives), though alcohol is served at most resorts and liveaboard boats. So, hotels and other locations might give you alcohol, but don't expect it at most local bars and locations ([especially many airports](https://liveandletsfly.com/maldives-alcohol-ban/)).